# Default to "Execute" when double-clicking on a shell script in PCManFM

Tags: shell-script, executable, pcmanfm

Is it possible to get an executable to execute by default?

What I mean is this.  I have an `.sh` file, which if I click on twice, it will show me this:

[image]

If I then click `Execute`, it does the right thing.  Is it possible to get it to `Execute` without being shown the `Execute File` dialog box?  So simply by double clicking the `.sh` file, it should do its thing without showing me the `Execute File` dialog box.

I am using Lubuntu/PCManFM if that info is needed.

Comment: You can use `xdg-mime query filetype shell_script.sh` to find the mime type of the script. Afterwards, use `xdg-mime query default mime_type` to see the current default application associated with the mime type, which is called upon `xdg-open` invocation. Then you can use `xdg-mime default default_application.desktop mime_type` to set the default application to be used. Find details [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/643473/318461)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a "Desktop Entry" like this (not 
tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
X-Created-By= name
Icon= icon
Exec="path_of_file" %u
Name=name of program
```

Comment: I created a [script to automatically generate these `.desktop`-files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/674052/318461), which can be considered. 
The `%u` means "pass all parameters to the script", [right?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189777/how-to-launch-shell-script-with-double-click-in-centos-7/189779#comment1272132_189779) Is the `Encoding` important? You could also add `Terminal=false` if needed.

Answer (score 3):

When double-clicking an icon on the desktop, to avoid presenting the "Execute File" dialog, do the following:

- Open File Manager
- Select Edit → Preferences → General
- Tick the option "Don't ask options on launch executable file"