# How to launch shell script with double click in CentOS 7

Tags: shell-script, desktop, icons

I need to be able to execute an executable shell script (`sh`) with a double click. I set the executable flag on the permissions for the file, and yet when I double click on it, it opens in a text editor. I do not have any options in my UI under the files properties menu to use a custom command or anything. It only lists various applications which are installed. I just want it to execute, nothing more. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You possibly have to log off and on again for some file managers to notice that change in executable flag [as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655803/318461)

Comment: You can use `xdg-mime query filetype shell_script.sh` to find the mime type of the script. Afterwards, use `xdg-mime query default mime_type` to see the current default application associated with the mime type, which is called upon `xdg-open` invocation. Then you can use `xdg-mime default default_application.desktop mime_type` to set the default application to be used. Find details [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/643473/318461)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To run your script by double clicking on its icon, you will need to create a `.desktop` file for it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My script
Comment=Test hello world script
Exec=/home/user/yourscript.sh
Icon=/home/user/youricon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Save the above as a file on your Desktop with a `.desktop` extension. Change `/home/user/yourscript.sh` and `/home/user/youricon.png` to the paths of your script and whichever icon you want it to have respectively and then you'll be able to launch by double clicking it.

Comment: I think in Centos 7 shuld be Exec[$e]='/home/user/yourscript.sh'

Comment: The above solution works fine for me without adding the Exec[$e] on Centos 7. Perhaps a later revision changed what is required.

Comment: @Cadoiz thanks for the edit, but desktop files ignore the shebang line. They are not scripts, so the shebang is completely irrelevant and unnecessary. As for `%u`, that is only needed if you want to pass parameters to the script, so isn't relevant here. See https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables.

Comment: Thank you! The reader of this Q/A can consider [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/674052/318461), where I provide a script to automatically generate these `.desktop`-files.

Answer (score 10):

Its actually very simple to do that. Just go to your Nautilus files preferences and click on the '*Behavior*' tab. Under '*Executable Text Files*' check '*Ask each time*' or '*Run executable text files when they are opened*'. Please look at the screenshot for reference.

[image: Files Preferences]

Comment: This is actually the correct answer.  You don't need a .desktop file.

Answer (score 2):

This involves using `dconf-editor` (`sudo yum install dconf-editor`):

Open `dconf-editor`, and navigate to the `/org/gnome/nautilus/preferences` menu.

Under "executable-text-activation", change "Use default value" to OFF, and "Custom value" to 'launch'.

You can then exit `dconf-editor`.

At this point, double-clicking on an icon which is a script, or a symbolic link to a script, will execute it, rather than opening up the file with `gedit`, which is what my system was doing.

So after changing the above preference, all I had to do is:

```
$ cd $HOME/Desktop

$ ln -s $HOME/bin/myscript.sh MyScript
```

and that's that.

(My system is GNOME Version 3.1.2 running on CentOs 7)

You have to log-out and log-in again before the double click on the desktop icon works.