# Unable to run .sh files by double-clicking them

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

When I try executing a *.sh file, I can run it from terminal, but not when double-clicking it form the file manager. The commands `chmod +x Test.sh` and
`chmod -x Test.sh` dont seem to work. Every time I double-click the file, it opens on my Text Editor. Here is the text in my file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

xdg-open https://www.google.com

cd home/<username>/Desktop

mkdir Test
cd Test
touch test.txt
```

The distro that I use is Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to log out and back in after marking the file as executable to apply the changes. The fastest way to do this is by using the shortcut `Ctrl + Alt + Delete`

Comment: This might not help everybody in the same situation, [see this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/673864/318461)

Answer (score 1):

`chmod -x Welcome.sh` is your exact problem.

`-x` is the same as `u-x`, or "remove the execute permission from my user". You need to *add* the execute permission with `chmod +x Welcome.sh`.

Also: You can change directory to your user home (if that's what `username` is) with just `cd ~` or `cd`. If it's another user's `$HOME`, then use `cd /home/<user>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xdg-mime query filetype shell_script.sh` to find the mime type of the script. Afterwards, use `xdg-mime query default mime_type` to see the current default application associated with the mime type, which is called upon `xdg-open` invocation. Then you can use `xdg-mime default default_application.desktop mime_type` to set the default application to be used.

The command output on my laptop is,

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype /opt/ros/foxy/setup.sh 
application/x-shellscript
$ xdg-mime query default application/x-shellscript
gvim.desktop
```