# What is the canonical way to run a .sh from file manager?

Tags: shell-script, opensuse, .desktop, dolphin

Hope, this belongs here and not e.g. on [SU](https://superuser.com/). I would like to make my life a bit easier and therefore want to be able to run a `script.sh` from file manager. This is possible in other distributions (or their software/presets), see here:
[image: PCManFM Feature] 
 but I don't want to switch to another FM just for this. The file is executable as per `chmod +x script.sh`. I'm using **openSUSE Leap version 15.1** with Plasma, Gnome or IceWM as a window-manager if this is important. The kernel is `4.12.14-lp151.28.91-default` and I have [**Files** (Gnome)](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus) 3.26.2, but I'm sure that this also applies to many other configurations. Dolphin  would also be an option for File Management.

I also tried to configure a [`.desktop`-file like suggested here](https://superuser.com/a/489715/910769), but didn't get it right.

Comment: Sometimes (while not in my case), it [helps logging off and on again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655803/318461). PCManFM would be a file manager to consider for the referenced feature. I included [the sample prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxwUV.png) in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the basics but not details of generating a `.desktop`-file.
[More Specification can be found here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables).

The mandatory (bare minimum) lines seem to be these:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Exec="path_of_file" %u
Terminal=false
```

The [%u is (only) needed if you want to pass parameters to the script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189777/how-to-launch-shell-script-with-double-click-in-centos-7/189779?noredirect=1#comment1272132_189779). There are also other possible entries such as `Name`, `Comment`, `Icon` or `X-Created-By`:

```
Name=My script
Comment=Test hello world script
Icon=/home/user/youricon.png
X-Created-By= your name
```

---

In order to improve the ease of creating these, I provide this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=\"$1\"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
$3" > "$2"
```

You can use this script like this: `$ make_script_click_runnable.sh "path_of_file" "YourClickRunnableFile.desktop"`. (*Depending on your link and file name, this usually also works without the quotes <kbd>"</kbd>.*)

If you want to include the optional parameters, this could be a call you use: `$ make_script_click_runnable.sh "path_of_file" "YourClickRunnableFile.desktop" $"Name=My script\nComment=Test hello world script\nIcon=/home/user/youricon.png\nX-Created-By= your name"`. Using the `$3`-parameter (see above), the optional ones are appended, but don't forget the `$` before `$Name=My Script\n...` - I didn't find a more elegant way yet to resolve the `\n`s.

---

You can also use basically the same script to create "hyperlinks" to URLs, as http, only the `Type` has to be changed and `URL` is used instead of `Exec`:

```
Type=Link
URL=http://example.com/your/link
Icon=text-html
```

Notice the standard-icon `text-html`. For more details on that, please consider [this answer on the respective question](https://superuser.com/a/1682826/910769).

Comment: The shebang line [can probably be omitted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189777/how-to-launch-shell-script-with-double-click-in-centos-7/189779?noredirect=1#comment1272132_189779)